# Removing xml:space attributes when using copy-of in xslt

Tags: xslt, xml-attribute

The following is part of the code in my input.xml file:

```
<info>
<name>
<surname>Sachin</surname>
<x> </x>
<given-names>J</given-names>
</name>
<x>, </x>
<name>
<surname>Sushant</surname>
<x> </x>
<given-names>K</given-names>
</name>
</info>
```

When I copy these nodes by using `copy-of` element as in

```
<xsl:copy-of select="info"></xsl:copy-of>
```

then the following output is generated:

```
<info>
<name>
<surname>Sachin</surname>
<x xml:space="preserve"> </x>
<given-names>J</given-names>
</name>
<x xml:space="preserve">, </x>
<name>
<surname>Sushant</surname>
<x xml:space="preserve"> </x>
<given-names>K</given-names>
</name>
</info>
```

I want to remove `xml:space="preserve"` from my output.xml file.

Comment: That's not a namespace. How do you generate your output?

Comment: Why do you want these removed? They explicitly declare that the space in the element needs to be there, which may be important. Many XML parsers would treat these as simply `<x/>` without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xsl:copy-of makes an exact copy. If you want to make any changes at all, however small, then you need to use the "modified identity template" coding pattern. In this case, the following template rule should do it:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@* except xml:space"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

(The "except" operator is XPath 2.0 - if you're stuck with 1.0, use `@*[name() != 'xml:space']`)

Comment: Thanks for reply.. I am new for Xslt.. i m using following code to copy .. <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>